# MYSQL how to unlock table if I used command LOCK table table_name WRITE;

Tags: mysql

This is my first question so please bear with me.

I have used this command:

```
LOCK "table table_name WRITE;"
```

in mysql workbench to lock any new people adding rows to this table. I cannot "unlock" this table.
Whenever I try entering different commands for example

```
select * from table_name
```

the screen just keeps on loading. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Rules for Lock Release**

---

When the table locks held by a session are released, they are all released at the same time. A session can release its locks explicitly, or locks may be released implicitly under certain conditions.

- A session can release its locks explicitly with UNLOCK TABLES.
- If a session issues a LOCK TABLES statement to acquire a lock while
  already holding locks, its existing locks are released implicitly
  before the new locks are granted.
- If a session begins a transaction (for example, with START
  TRANSACTION), an implicit UNLOCK TABLES is performed, which causes
  existing locks to be released.

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Is there another way to prevent inserting rows into a table in the database? To prevent for example users signing up as an admin

Comment: What you are saying seems more appropriate in the application logic side, i.e.: you should check that stuff before sending it to the DB. IMHO Locking mechanisms (whether in tables or rows) are intended to enforce reliability and consistency in a concurrent context (for example, a user tries to change data that another one  is reading). You could check out [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_locking) for more information.