# How to unlock a specifi table by table name in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

below sql statement is not currect but i just give a example

> unlock tables where `Table`="my_table";

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083031/mysql-how-to-unlock-table-if-i-used-command-lock-table-table-name-write

Comment: ya i got my ans
thanks